# SQL INSERT from 1 table to another , WHERE existing columns in both tables share the same content

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables,

Table 1 :columns = id, Category

Table 2 : columns = Category, CategoryID

I want to insert the 'id' from the Table 1 into the 'CategoryID' column in Table 2, where the contents of 'Category' in both tables are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to update `Table2` with the `id` from `Table1` and you can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET CategoryID = (SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Category = Table2.Category)
```

Depending on the database that you use, this can be done also with a join, but the syntax differs for each case.